# Iterating over an Array using iterators

Tags: c++, arrays, split, iterator

I want to iterate over a simple double array using iterators. I wonder how I can do that actually.

What I would like to have is something like this:

```
void foo(double* array, size_t size)
{
    std::vector<double> real(size);
    std::vector<double> imag(size);
    auto arrBegin = std::begin(array); // this of course doesn't work
    auto arrEnd = std::end(array); // this of course doesn't work

    bool toggle = false;

    std::partition_copy(arrBegin, arrEnd, std::begin(real), std::begin(imag),
                [&toggle] (int) {return toggle != toggle});

    //Do other stuff
}
```

As some of you might guess, the array is an interleaved complex number, that I would like to split up into arrays of real and imaginary part.

Is there a way to do that using an array that I receive as a pointer if I know the size of the array, or do I need to use a separate class like std::vector for the array in order to work with iterators?

I would appreciate to use std::partition_copy(), but I am open to other ideas.

Note: I cannot use std::array because the array size is not known during compile time. std::vector would be possible, but I actually want to see whether it's possible to do it without std::vector as I receive the array from an API and want to use it as it is.

Comment: That's why you should use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: Note that your vectors aren't big enough to hold the output ranges.

Comment: On an unrelated note, if you have a *size* use `size_t` instead. On a 64-bit system it's most likely an alias of an unsigned 64-bit integer type just like `uint64_t`, but it conveys more semantical information to the reader of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array` and `array + size` as your iterators.

You probably also want to use [inserter-iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) for the vectors.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

std::partition_copy(array, array + size,
                    std::back_inserter(real),
                    std::back_inserter(imag),
                    [&toggle](int t){ return t != toggle; });
```

Comment: This answer requires some explanations. What are you doing, this is pretty advanced.

Comment: @Chiel: Which part of this is unclear and not covered by the respective documentations?

Comment: Why the back inserters? Why the modification to the lambda function? Your solution looks elegant if only I understood it.

Comment: @Chiel: Inserters because you want to insert (check the documentation of [`partition_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_copy). The OP's lambda code was ill-formed. I'm assuming that the OP knows how the algorithms work; the question gave me no reason to believe otherwise.

Comment: Thanks man. Works like a charm. Btw: are the back_inserters in any way preferable to std::begin / std::end if I preallocate the vectors? Oh and my lambda function actually works, as I have shown it above, What did I do wrong?

Comment: @FreddyKay: You cannot "preallocate" vectors. You can actually *fill* vectors with values ahead of time, but that seems wasteful to me: why create meaningless values only so that they are immediately overwritten? You could of course still *reserve* capacity in the vectors, but that's unrelated to inserting.

Comment: @FreddyKay IINM, your original lambda always returns `false` and does not use its parameter. That's quite fishy indeed.

Comment: @FreddyKay: and of course you don't know the result sizes ahead-of-time, so with reserve+insert, the result is easy to consume.